# jQuery animate not working for flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I have a series of divs with a flex element to them, each with an equal flexibility. When I click one of them this function fires:

```
// hides and unhides and changes the size of elements...
function button_flexchange(element,quantity) {
    $(element).css('flex',''+quantity);
}
```

Which works - essentially it just hides and unhides an element, so pass button_flexchange('#thisdiv', 0) and it will hide the #thisdiv by changing its flex value to 0.

What I think would be NICER is to use the animate function in jQuery to hide it, so more like this:

```
// hides and unhides and changes the size of elements...
function button_flexchange(element,quantity) {
    $(element).animate({
        'flex',''+quantity
    }, {duration: 2000});
}
```

But this isnt working. I have tried changing the flex to the flex-grow setting but im just not familiar enough with the relationship between jquery and flex to make this work.

A sample of my CSS:

```
#help_icons { width: 150px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; }
.help_icon { margin: 0 5px 0 5px; }
.help_icon:hover { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)); filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)); cursor: pointer; }
#help_icon_peerassess { background: url('/css/images/icons/peer_assessment.png') no-repeat; }
#help_icon_peerhelp { background: url('/css/images/icons/help_icon.png') no-repeat; }
#help_icon_helpmypeers { background: url('/css/images/icons/help_others.png') no-repeat; }
```

And the HTML for these elements:

```
<div id="help_icons">
    <div id="help_icon_peerassess" class="help_icon" title="Request this work be peer assessed"></div>
    <div id="help_icon_peerhelp" class="help_icon" style="" title="Request help from your peers"></div>
    <div id="help_icon_helpmypeers" class="help_icon" style="" title="Offer your help to others"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle (I use images but this uses text): https://jsfiddle.net/gwefLn8q/2/

Thank you!